# Magento2 - Layered Navigation how to create multiselect functionality using code

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.1.2, multiple-select-layered

Magento2 version is - **2.1.2**

I am creating **custom module** for **layered navigation** and i want to create **multiselect options functionality** for layerednavigation.

I have already displayed **checkbox over there** by overriding the template of layered navigation in my custom module now what i need is how to select those checkbox  as multiselect**.

> I have seen there are **lot of extenstions available** for that but i
>   want to **do it with code**.is it possible ?

Is there any **good tutorial** to override **layered navigation module** and create this kind of functionality ?

Advance Thanks.

Comment: is your ajax filter working ?? only multi select is not working only ?? @ManthanDave

Comment: @MohammadMujassam - Firstly i have started multi select option i dont mind if its work with post on page referesh , if its work then i will implement ajax at last

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to create you own/custom [theme](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/create-custom-theme-magento-2-part-1/)..
inside your theme directory create folder **Magento_LayeredNavigation** (if not available already) inside this folder copy the all template file from core module `Magento\LayeredNavigation\view\frontend\templates` into `Magento_LayeredNavigation\template`.

now you can override the layered navigation design and codes..

for multi-select you need to write the url, Sample url re-write method given as below you can customize it as per you requirement.

sample helper function given below..

```
public function getFilterUrls($params,$filter,$value){
    $currentCatUrl = $this->getCurrentCatUrl();
    unset($params['id']);
    unset($params['isAjax']);
    unset($params['_']);
    //$value = str_replace(',', '', $value);
    if (isset($params[$filter])) {
        $filterArray = explode(',', $params[$filter]);
        $checkValue = in_array($value, $filterArray);
        $remVelue = array_diff($filterArray, [$value]);
        $remVelue = implode(',', $remVelue);
    }
    if(isset($params[$filter]) and $params[$filter] == $value){
        unset($params[$filter]);
        $url = $currentCatUrl . '?' . http_build_query($params);
    }elseif (!empty($params[$filter]) && $params[$filter] !== ',' && $params[$filter] !== $value && $checkValue == FALSE) {
        $urlValues = $params[$filter];
        unset($params[$filter]);
        $url = $currentCatUrl . '?' . http_build_query($params) . '&' . $filter . '='.$urlValues.','.$value;
    }elseif (isset($params[$filter]) && $params[$filter] !== ',' && $params[$filter] !== $value && $checkValue == TRUE) {
        unset($params[$filter]);
        $url = $currentCatUrl . '?' . http_build_query($params) . '&' . $filter . '='.$remVelue;
    }
    else{
        unset($params[$filter]);
        $url = $currentCatUrl . '?' . http_build_query($params) . '&' . $filter . '=' . $value ;
    }
    return $url;
}
```

where `$params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();`

AND **$filter** is new/ old parameter name which you want make multiselect/select.

AND **$value** is the value you want for the parameter you passed..

AND **$currentCatUrl** current category url which you will get from registory.

call the above helper method in **Magento_LayeredNavigation\template\view.phtml**.
**Magento_LayeredNavigation\template\view.phtml** is the file where you make the changes for layered navigation..

this will return the filter URL for both multiselect & sigle select.

**update 1:** 
formate example

```
<a href="<?php echo $block->escapeUrl($helper->getFilterUrls($params,'for','1')) ?>">
                <input type="checkbox" name="" value="l" id="check1"  <?php echo $this->getRequest()->getParam('for')=='1'?'checked':'' ?>>
                <label for="check1"> </label> <div class="anchor-text">Men</div>
```

Comment: please check the method I have given all the filters which is already there will not be remove .. if you are clicking on the same checkbox which is already applied then only it will remove

Comment: please check my update 1

Comment: create helper in any of your module and load into the **view.phtml** (template) as given **$helper = $this->helper('Vendor\Module\Helper\Data')**

you can refer this site to create the helper https://www.cloudways.com/blog/create-helpers-in-magento-2/

Comment: May be you are missing some param or some thing you can debug it.. basically the logic will be same as i have given... some params may changes as per your requirement...  and yes you can use this anywhere

Comment: okay i have done all the things and now page is blank when i am trying to access  the page. is there any other issue ? -  <?php $helper = $this->helper('vendorname\LayeredNavigation\Helper\Data'); ?>
<?php $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams(); ?>
<a href="<?php echo $block->escapeUrl($helper->getFilterUrls($params,'for','1')) ?>"></a> - i have puted this line on my view.phtml top